# Call external API until request is marked as complete

Tags: node.js

I have following situation.

I have a service which runs jobs on a remote service and exposes API for calling the same.

I have an array of jobs which needs to be executed on remote server and it works fine, when used Promises.

The flow is as below

Inside main function I get a token. On .then() of the same, I initiate my for loop for jobs and pass the JobID and token. This second function returns me the execution_ID of each job. On the .then() of this second function I pass token and execution_id. This returns me the status of the job.

My problem is; when a job is executed, it send me queued, initiated and completed as status. When the status turns to 'completed' I get results of the job; which I need to display.

I tried using a setTimeOut() inside the last function, but I'm not sure when it will end as each job may take different time.

Is there a way I can call this third function multiple time unless the status changes to 'completed'?

Below is the code

```
app.get('/ExecuteJobs', function (req, res) {
var commandArraay = ["job1", "job2"]
var sTokenID;
getAuthToken()
    .then(function (token) {
        commandArraay.forEach(function (element) {
            getExecutionID(token, element)
                .then(function (executionResult) {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        getExecutionResult(token, executionResult.id, executionResult)
                            .then(function (updateArray) {
                                console.log("Final Status " + "ID: " + executionResult.id + " Status: " + executionResult.status);
                                // if(executionResult.)
                            })
                    }, 10000)

                })
        })

    })
res.send('Done');
});



// Function to get the auth token
async function getAuthToken(token) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0;
        var pUserID = 'uname'
        var pPwd = 'pwd'
        performhttpsRequest('/<remote_api>/tokens', 'POST', {
            sAuth: "Basic " + new Buffer(pUserID + ":" +    pPwd).toString("base64")
    }, "0", token,
        function (data1) {
            sTokenID = data1.token;
            resolve(sTokenID);
        })
})
}
// Function to post the command and get execution ID
async function getExecutionID(tokenID, command, executionID) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        performhttpsRequest('/<remote_api>/executecommand', 'POST', {
        command: command
    }, "1", tokenID,
        function (data1) {
            var executionID = data1.execution_id;
            resolve(executionID);
        })
})
}
// Function to get the execution results for an ID
async function getExecutionResult(tokenID, executionID, result) {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    performhttpsRequest('/<remote_api>/execution_result/' + executionID, 'GET', {

    }, "1", tokenID,
        function (result) {
            resolve(result.result);
        })
})
```

}

Comment: Please, don't describe the code. Post it instead. The question should contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: If you absolutely need a result after the enqueued job is settled, then I don't see how you can have any other choice other than retrying to check the status every n-seconds.

Comment: Thanks @NikKyriakides - But that is the main problem. If I understand it right; I cannot use a for loop or while loop to keep checking. What is the way to keep checking?

Comment: One way is to use recursion; I wrote up an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely need a result after the enqueued job is settled, then I don't see how you can have any other choice other than retrying to check the status every n-seconds.

Here's how I would do it. A recursive function that retries a request n-times, each time waiting n-seconds:

```js
// Mock request, resolves { status: 'completed' } 20% of the time.
const request = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    Math.random() < 0.2
      ? resolve({ status: 'completed', foo: 'bar' })
      : resolve({ status: 'pending' })
  })
}

const retryToCompletion = async ({ wait, retries }) => {
  console.log('Retries left:', retries)

  const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => request().then(resolve).catch(reject), wait)
  })

  if (result.status === 'completed')
    return result

  if (retries)
    return retryToCompletion({ wait, retries: --retries })

  throw new Error('Retry attempts exhausted')
}

retryToCompletion({ wait: 1000, retries: 5 })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error)
```

That being said, some API's that work with [BASE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) queues offer a handle to a [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) connection that notifies when a job is completed. If the API offers that, then you should ditch retrying and use the completed notification instead.

Comment: upvoting for the retry stuff. There is also the npm package [retry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/retry)

Answer (score 0):

making GET calls until completion

```
/**
 * cbk be called when..complete execution ok
 */
function completeExecution(tokenID, executionID, result, callPeriod, cbk){
    return getExecutionResult(tokenID, executionID, result).then(res=>{

        if(res.completed){
            return cbk(null, res)
        }

        setTimeout(function(){
            return completeExecution(cbk); //reenqueue
        }, callPeriod)
    }).catch(cbk) //up to you to abort or insist
}
```

Then you can promisify `completeExecution` (with `util.promisify` or by yourself)