# React. How to send a request until I receive a positive response from the server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, fetch, settimeout

I need to send a response to the server with the data, and then send a request with a delay (the server must have time to count the response). And if the server has not yet prepared a response, send a request until I receive a positive response.

I think my code must look something like this:

```
...
dispatch(finishSession());
 if (res === failer) {
      setTimeout(async () => dispatch(getSessionScore()), 1000);
}
...
```

Should I use useEffect, or are there any alternatives?

Comment: If you use a socket connection instead, the server can simply send back a reply whenever they are done.

Comment: Thanks for idea, but it's no socket connection in this project!

Comment: yes, useEffect is appropriate

Comment: (note that React / useEffect is mostly irrelevant) Ok, in that case simply keep using `setTimeout()` to run an API request. If the server sends back the reply, setState. If the server sends "I'm still busy", call setTimeout again to schedule a new request.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Call external API until request is marked as complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54511678/call-external-api-until-request-is-marked-as-complete)